# What does "illegal argument in functor" mean in Common Lisp?

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

*Note* Learning Lisp

I am getting this error:

```
Illegal argument in functor position: (EVALEXP (CDR MAIN-LIST) BIND-LIST) 
in ((EVALEXP(CDR   MAIN-LIST) BIND-LIST))
```

from this:

```
(defun evalexp (main-list bind-list)

(if (eq nil (cdr main-list)) 
    (  (if  (eq nil  (atom (car main-list))) (evalexp (car main-list) bind-list) ) )

( (print (car main-list))
  (evalexp (cdr main-list) bind-list) )
)
```

main-list contains this list:

```
(and 1 (or a b))
```

What is in bind-list doesn't matter because I am not using it yet. I am trying to loop through the list printing out each car. Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extra parentheses.

Normally the first thing after an opening parenthesis is a function name. You have another opening parenthesis there in some cases, which is a syntax error, as you saw.

You also seem to want a statement block. `progn` often fits the bill. You could use a block for the inner `if`, but it's really not necessary since it would contain only one statement.

```
(defun evalexp (main-list bind-list)
  (if (eq nil (cdr main-list)) 
      (if  (eq nil (atom (car main-list))) (evalexp (car main-list) bind-list) )
      (progn
        (print (car main-list))
        (evalexp (cdr main-list) bind-list) )
  )
)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I really appreciate you pointing out the error! This language is harder to learn because of how different it is from others.

Comment: I really have to thank you because I had no idea how to run multiple forms, as I assumed thats where the error came from, but I did not think Lisp offered it. I appreciate it greatly. It'll help me in getting this homework done. Cheers!

Comment: All of PROGN, PROG1 and PROG2 are (occasionally) useful. Although I find that I use PROGN and PROG1 more than I use PROG2.