# Lisp Illegal argument in functor position

Tags: lisp, lispworks

Hello can anyone help me out?

```
(defun f(x)
    (LIST ((* 2 x) (* 3 x)))
)

(f 1)
```

I get this, `Illegal argument in functor position: (* 2 X) in ((* 2 X) (* 3 X))`.

Comment: If you want the results of those operations in a list, then you have too many parens. Just use `(list (* 2 x) (* 3 x))`

Comment: It's good practice to do a bit of research before posting questions.  In this case, searching for the error message "illegal argument in functor position" turns up [two other related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=illegal+argument+in+functor+position+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "illegal argument in functor" mean in Common Lisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662226/what-does-illegal-argument-in-functor-mean-in-common-lisp)

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
(defun f (x)
    (list (* 2 x) (* 3 x)))
```

You have an extra set of parentheses around the arguments to `list`. When an expression is a list, the first thing is supposed to be the function to call, so

```
((* 2 x) (* 3 x))
```

is not a valid expression because `(* 2 x)` is not a function.