# LISP: Illegal argument in functor position

Tags: list, macros, lisp, common-lisp

My code looks like this:

```
(defmacro createList (a b c)
  (let ((lst (list a b c)))
    (write lst)))

(createList 1 2 3 )
```

I get:

```
Illegal argument in functor position: 1 in (1 2 3).
```

I know there is a simillar question here:
[Lisp Illegal argument in functor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297834/lisp-illegal-argument-in-functor-position)

But I can't adjust the answer to my problem. Where is the parentheses problem? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the `write` function is its argument. So, the result of `(write "Tom")` is `"Tom"` (the fact that it writes to the output stream is a side effect of the function).

Macros return a form to be evaluated, which typically means a list.

Your macro creates the list `(1 2 3)`, and then writes it out. The `write` is evaluated at macro expansion time, NOT "runtime". Since `write` returns it's argument as its return value, and `write` is the last function called, the result of the macro function is the result of the `write` function, or, in this case, `(1 2 3)`.

`(1 2 3)` is then evaluated, but if you try typing `(1 2 3)` in to the top level, it will see the `1` as the first argument of the form, and try to evaluate that as a function -- which it's not, it's just the number 1.

If you want to see what you macro will expand, you can try: `(macroexpand '(createlist 1 2 3))`

You can see the result below:

```
[2]> (macroexpand '(createlist 1 2 3))
(1 2 3)
(1 2 3) ;
T
```

You see the first `(1 2 3)`, which is the result of your `write`. You then see the second `(1 2 3)`, which is the result of the macro expansion (discussed above), followed by the `T`, which is the result of the `macroexpand` function.

So that's what's going on. Not clear how to fix it, as it's not clear what you want to do.

Perhaps this is more what you're looking to do:

```
(defmacro createlist (a b c)
  `(list ,a ,b ,c))

[5]> (macroexpand `(createlist 1 2 3))
(LIST 1 2 3) ;
T
```

Comment: WOW! This was fast! And it helped a LOT!! I didn't know about the `write` function since I'm starting learning LISP. The solution You provided at the end is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

`write` returns the object you pass to it as it's first argument. Thus, you're returning `lst` from the macro. Whatever you return from the macro is considered lisp code.

When running your code, you should see

```
(1 2 3)
```

on the standard output just before the error. That's what you're giving to `write`: The result of `(list a b c)` with `a` being bound to `1` etc.

The first element of a list in lisp code is the function being called. Obviously, `1`, which is the first element of this list, isn't a function.

In order to debug such errors, using `macroexpand` is often helpful:

```
(defmacro createList (a b c)
  (let ((lst (list a b c)))
     (write lst)))

(format t "~%Expanded ~a~%" (macroexpand-1 '(createList 1 2 3)))
```

[(Live)](http://ideone.com/PoGXB5)